# CMD: IF statement not workin

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd

If I run this:

`IF EXIST "%DRVL%:\Windows\syswow64" (SET "arch=x64") ELSE (SET "arch=x86")`

`IF "%arch%"=="x86" DO (
  ECHO x86
)`

`IF "%arch%"=="x64" DO (
  ECHO x64
)`

Than its display this:

`x86
'DO is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
x64`

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`IF` doesn't require `DO` (`FOR` does).

Try this:

```
IF EXIST "%DRVL%:\Windows\syswow64" (SET "arch=x64") ELSE (SET "arch=x86")

IF "%arch%"=="x86" (
  ECHO x86
)

IF "%arch%"=="x64" (
  ECHO x64
)
```

Formatted slightly different to demonstrate nesting `IF` conditions:

```
IF EXIST "%DRVL%:\Windows\syswow64" (
    SET "arch=x64"
) ELSE (
    SET "arch=x86"
)

IF "%arch%"=="x86" (
    ECHO x86
) ELSE (
    IF "%arch%"=="x64" ECHO x64
)
```